# Have whips been fixed in DF2012?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the last version of Dwarf Fortress I was informed that generally foreign weapons were not worth using, with the exception of whips and scourges, because the physics engine worked using speed and impact area, and turned them into lightsabers. Is this still the case in Dwarf Fortress 2012?

I'd read the wiki, but frankly, that article confuses me more then most academic chemistry papers I've read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of DF2012, a hit with most any whip will cause bone chipping, extreme pain, and incapacitation, pretty much regardless of what armor the victim is wearing.

Comment: So yes. Got it.